# Should usability experts be included when testing the first initial prototypes?

Tags: user-centered-design, hci, expert-review

My project consists of three iterations:

1. Low-fidelity usability tests
2. Redefined prototype usability tests
3. Final prototype usability tests.

I am unsure whether to include the HCI expert review session from the first iteration.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is the HCI expert review? And what do you want to include it in?

Comment: The HCI expert review is a formal inspection of the prototypes by some UX/HCI professionals who will attempt to perform some tasks for the interface. It will include similar tasks I will perform with the users, but feedback will be more technical and in detail.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What are you trying to achieve with the usability tests in all three phases?

Comment: @Majo0od I will start to test 3 prototypes in the first iteration, then based on the results and observations of the first iteration, I will test a high fidelity prototype in the second iteration. Finally I will refine and modify the final prototype in the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take it one step further than just including them. But yes include them in the review I think having another set of eyes with additional views could help the effort.

**Why not include them in the prototype generation?**

I am a huge fan of parallel prototyping to increase idea generation. [Parallel Prototyping Leads to Better
Design Results, More Divergence,
and Increased Self-Efficacy](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~spdow/files/PrototypingParallel-TOCHI10.pdf)

You could do something like google ventures does and include them during the prototype creation process to add to the idea generation process when making prototypes. Check out their [design sprints](http://www.gv.com/sprint/)

**Possible Reason to leave out experts in low fidelity prototype reviews**

- Timelines, you cant get in contact with them due to them being from another office or contracting firm that cant cater to your deadlines and you need to iterate. I would rather keep iterating than put it on pause to wait for an expert.
- Cost. Maybe they are contractors and does the cost pay off here or later. I would argue to do it during the low fidelity area as opposed to the high fidelity but i think one needs some data to see where UX expertise is best used if you cant afford it throughout the entire design process.

List item

Comment: Thanks @Bob Sinclar, I also like the concept of including them in the prototype generation phase.

Comment: Anytime I think you get improvements using them at all phases but if you can't due to resources where would that time best be spent. And I don't think there's a clear cut answer

Answer (score 0):

A question on your question: If the expert does not understand the first insights being gathered, or could not have influence on probably missing information, how could they create the best possible next level prototype or wireframes?

If you think that you should conduct a test, because you (the expert) do not know enough (which is, well, why you test at all), then the answer is: *Yes, absolutely*. 
Because that is why you do it in the first place.

Participating in usability tests is crucial to usability engineers. And, for all the nodders, for the product owners/managers as well.